# Embedding a <form> inside a <div>

Tags: html, css

Whenever I try to embed a `<form>` inside a `<div>` (with a css file changing formatting etc) the input bar doesn't fit the div like I am trying to get and I can't seem to be able to change it without hard-coding the positioning which I don't want since I may change the size of that div in the future and I don't wanna mess with the input field etc.

[screenshot of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdkSw.png)

As you may see, the form isn't within the div's border and I want it to fit nicely at the bottom of it so it's like a chat box.

Here is my current HTML

```css
#game-chat-div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 15em;
  border-style: double;
  margin: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#chat-form {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id='game-chat-div'>
  <div id='game-chat-messages'>Hello</div>
  <form id='chat-form'>
    <input id='game-chat-input' type='text'>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am really stuck on this and I would love if someone could help me out.

Comment: Where do you want to position the `input`? Using `position: fixed;` like you are doing, is taking the element out of the flow and positioning it where you are telling it to do it, at the bottom left of the window.

Comment: Putting fixed inside fixed is often a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding below css,

```
#game-chat-input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and updating other css as per snippet. For this you need to make that form div relative to parent. This will grab the parent width.

```css
#game-chat-div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 15em;
  border-style: double;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#chat-form {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#game-chat-input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='game-chat-div'>
  <div id='game-chat-messages'>Hello</div>
  <form id='chat-form'>
    <input id='game-chat-input' type='text'>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#game-chat-div` position must be `relative`
and `#chat-form` must be `absolute` and `left:0 , bottom: 0 , margin:0 auto`

If you can't understand with this descriptions , ask me to attach an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by simply changing the position of the #chat-form to absolute like this

```
 #chat-form {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code like the following, then you can achieve this goal:

```css
#game-chat-div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 15em;
  border-style: double;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chat-form {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
}

.position-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="position-fixed">
    <div id='game-chat-div'>
      <div id='game-chat-messages'>Hello</div>
      <form id='chat-form'>
        <input id='game-chat-input' type='text'>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8fLdysb1/) is a link to a fiddle.

The changes are minor corrections in your original code.